# Multithreading and MessageDlgPos

Tags: multithreading, delphi

Hi I'm doing a code MessageDlgPos running five threads at the same time, the code is this:

```
type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    text: string;
    property ReturnValue;
  end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  if Terminated then
    Exit;
  MessageDlgPos(text, mtInformation, [mbOk], 0, 100, 200);
end;

procedure TForm1.btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  LThread: TMyThread;
  i: Integer;
begin

  For i := 1 to 5 do
  begin
    LThread := TMyThread(Sender);
    try
      LThread.text := 'hi';
      LThread.FreeOnTerminate := True;
    except
      LThread.Free;
      raise;
    end;
    LThread.Resume;
  end;
end;
```

The problem is that Delphi XE always returns the following error and does not execute anything:

First chance exception at $ 7524B727. Exception class EAccessViolation with message 'Access violation at address 00D0B9AB. Write of address 8CC38309 '. Process tester.exe (6300)

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As David Heffernan pointed out, `MessageDlgPos()` cannot safely be called outside of the main UI thread, and you are not managing the thread correctly.  Your code needs to look more like this instead:

```
type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    text: string;
    property ReturnValue;
  end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  // no need to check Terminated here, TThread already
  // does that before calling Execute()...
  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      MessageDlgPos(text, mtInformation, [mbOk], 0, 100, 200);
    end
  );
end;

procedure TForm1.btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  LThread: TMyThread;
  i: Integer;
begin
  For i := 1 to 5 do
  begin
    LThread := TMyThread.Create(True);
    LThread.text := 'hi';
    LThread.FreeOnTerminate := True;
    LThread.Start;
  end;
end;
```

I would suggest a slightly different variation:

```
type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  private
    fText: string;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(const aText: string); reintroduce;
    property ReturnValue;
  end;

constructor TMyThread.Create(const aText: string);
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  fText := aText;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  // no need to check Terminated here, TThread already
  // does that before calling Execute()...
  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      MessageDlgPos(fText, mtInformation, [mbOk], 0, 100, 200);
    end
  );
end;

procedure TForm1.btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  For i := 1 to 5 do
  begin
    TMyThread.Create('hi');
  end;
end;
```

But either way, if you don't like using `TThread.Synchronize()` to delegate to the main thread (thus only displaying 1 dialog at a time) then you cannot use `MessageDlgPos()` at all, since it is only safe to call in the main UI thread.  You can use `Windows.MessageBox()` instead, which can be safely called in a worker thread without delegation (but then you lose the ability to specify its screen position, unless you access its `HWND` directly by using a thread-local hook via `SetWindowsHookEx()` to intercept the dialog's creation and discover its `HWND`):

```
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  Windows.MessageBox(0, PChar(fText), PChar(Application.Title), MB_OK or MB_ICONINFORMATION);
  );
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many problems. The biggest one is here:

```
LThread := TMyThread(Sender);
```

`Sender` is a button. Casting to a thread is simply wrong and the cause of your exception. Casting a button to a thread doesn't make it so. It's still a button.

You likely mean to create a thread instead.

```
LThread := TMyThread.Create(True);
```

You cannot show VCL UI outside the main thread. The call to `MessageDlgPos` breaks that rule. If you do need to show UI at that point, you'll need to use `TThread.Synchronize` to have the code execute in the main thread.

Your exception handler makes no sense to me. I think you should remove it.

`Resume` is deprecated. Use `Start` instead.

Comment: I suggest you debug your program. I've shown you the most glaring errors in that code you showed.

Comment: also delete the line of the messagebox but still does not work the problem must be in the creation of the thread

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: more accurately, you cannot access **VCL/FMX** UI elements outside of the main thread. The `MessageDlg...()` functions display a popup `TForm`, so they are only safe to use in the main thread. Win32 dialogs, like `MessageBox()`, can be safely called in threads. Win32 UIs in general can be used in any thread, as long as they are accessed only by the same thread that creates them, and that thread has its own message loop (which modal dialogs like `MessageBox()` handle internally). The way VCL/FMX manages these UIs internally is what makes them unsafe outside of the main thread.

Comment: @Nemo I was hoping you'd be able to write the code for yourself. Remy wrote out what I described. I guess you got something wrong along the way.